# Getting <br /> while inserting value into mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am getting a `<br />` statement while inserting the values into MySQL using php.
 I have tried changing the insert statement as well as echo statement but nothing works.

```
 <?php
     if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
     $userfullname=$_POST['userfullname'];
     $usernickname=$_POST['usernickname'];
     $usermail=$_POST['usermail'];
     $userusname=$_POST['userusname'];
     $useruspassword=$_POST['useruspassword']; 
     $user="";
     $curr_timestamp = now(); 
     define('HOST','********');
     define('USER','*******');
     define('PASS','*****');
     define('DB','********'); 
     $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect'); 
     $sql = "INSERT INTO 0_users (`ID`, `user_login`, `user_pass`,    `user_nicename`, `user_email`, `user_url`, `user_registered`, `user_activation_key`, `user_status`, `display_name`) VALUES (NULL, '$userusname', '$useruspassword', '$usernickname', '$usermail', '', '$curr_timestamp', '', '0', '$userfullname')"; 
     $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$sql)); 
     if(isset($check)){
     echo "success";
      }else{
    echo "Invalid Username or Password";
    }
   mysqli_close($con);
   }else{
   echo "error try again";
   }
   ?>
```

Comment: can you show what values inserted when you run this code.

Comment: the values which are posted from android has been used i have used echo to  check whether the values are passed and the values are posted to this php page.

Comment: show us then what these variables have `$userfullname,$usernickname,$usermail,$userusname,$useruspassword` by doing `var_dump()` for each

Comment: in which filed  your are getting <br/ >

Comment: in php str_replace() function availble you can remove <br> tag str_replace('<br/>','',$yourfiledvalue)

Comment: instead of showing echo statement as success or invalid it show <br />

Comment: You have usernicename instead of usernickname. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
         if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
         $userfullname=preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $_POST['userfullname'] );
         $usernickname=preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $_POST['usernickname']);
         $usermail=preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $_POST['usermail']);
         $userusname=preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $_POST['userusname']);
         $useruspassword=preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $_POST['useruspassword']); 
         $user="";
         $curr_timestamp = now(); 
         define('HOST','********');
         define('USER','*******');
         define('PASS','*****');
         define('DB','********'); 
         $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect'); 
         $sql = "INSERT INTO 0_users (`user_login`, `user_pass`,    `user_nicename`, `user_email`, `user_url`, `user_registered`, `user_activation_key`, `user_status`, `display_name`) VALUES ('$userusname', '$useruspassword', '$usernickname', '$usermail', '', '$curr_timestamp', '', '0', '$userfullname')"; 
         $check = mysqli_query($con,$sql); 
         if(isset($check)){
         echo "success";
          }else{
        echo "Invalid Username or Password";
        }
       mysqli_close($con);
       }else{
       echo "error try again";
       }
```

?>

Comment: I have used the code as you have mentioned but still getting same error

Comment: no instead of showing these echo statements                            if(isset($check)){
         echo "success";
          }else{
        echo "Invalid Username or Password";
        }                                                                                                        i am getting <br /> in echo statement

Comment: try print_r($check); after $check; what are you getting.

Comment: It doesn't print anything

Comment: yes i have updated the code and tried still i didn't get anything

Comment: is it inserted to database?

Comment: pls show your complete code. did you configured the host,username and password of the database?

Comment: whats your tablename

Comment: why you put null value for id